# Entity Framework Code First Many-to-Many tries to create duplicates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my application I have a many-to-many join between Appointments and AppointmentTypes. When the database is created a Table called AppointmentTypesAppointments is created as the joining table.

When I create and save a new appointment which has multiple appointment types the joining table is populated correctly.

However, when I later edit and re-save the appointment, without making any changes to the appointment types, the application tries to create duplicate entries in the joining table (AppointmentTypesAppointments).

How can I stop the application from trying to create these duplicate rows?

```
// appointments are fetched as a group...
using (var context = new SchedulerContext())
        {
            //return GetAll();
            IQueryable<Appointment> queryable = context.Appointments;

            // check if any records exist
            if (queryable.Count() == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"No Appointment details found within the database");
            }

           return queryable.ToList();
        }
//-----------------------------------------
// user then edits a single appointment and it is saved as below....
using (var context = new SchedulerContext())
{
    try
    {
        var originalEntity = context.Appointments.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        context.Entry(originalEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(appointment);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return SuccessResult();
    }
    catch
    {
        return OtherFailResult(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This post was very unclear. please explain and add some code for your save and fetch methods.

Answer (score 0):

How do you do edit and resave? It's obvious that EF doesn't know that you are doing an update on an existing entity. You need check for existence to decide whether it's a add or save.

Comment: The appointment is retrieved using a context (e.g. context A) connection. the record is then edited and re-saved using a new context (e.g. context B).

Comment: ... continued... (sorry) I get the original record back on the new context using the id, update the values using the appointment I have edited, then do context.Save which updates everything else fine but not the appointment types collection

Comment: I think that may be the problem, why would you need two context. Please post some code , so we can help you out.

Comment: I think you need do attach the appointment to the current context, take a look at this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Comment: I have added the code that is used to get the collection of appointments from which the user selects one to edit...